# Copying All Files Between Directories in Terminal (Mac)

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, terminal, copy

When I try to copy files from one directory to another on Mac, I use the following command:

> sudo cp -r dir1/* dir2/

At first glance, it seems that it works well. However, it always skips the files like .git, .gitignore and .htaccess. Why is that? Do those files have some kind of privileged status?

If it helps, the dir1 is the result of

> git clone

command that I run prior to that.

Answer (score 18):

In the command:

```
cp -r dir1/* dir2/
```

the shell expands `dir1/*` and passes the result to `cp`. The `*` pattern does **not** match a leading `.`, that is it matches files which are usually visible. You can use the pattern `dir1/.*` to match those entries beginning with a `.`, but for `cp` there is a better way. From `man cp`:

> If source_file designates a directory, cp copies the directory and the entire subtree connected at that point.  If the source_file ends in a /, the contents of the directory are copied rather than the directory itself.

So what you are after is:

```
cp -r dir1/ dir2/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include the hidden files and folders if you replace the * (star) with a . (dot) in your command.